ERROR: pg_partman function partman.create_parent() does not exist
I had error during creating of partition on table.
During creating table and making partition rule
CREATE TABLE test_table (
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    last_seen timestamptz not NULL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE ("last_seen");

SELECT partman.create_parent(
    p_parent_table := 'public.test_table',
    p_control := 'last_seen',
    p_interval := '1 day'
);

got error
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function partman.create_parent(p_parent_table => unknown, p_control => unknown, p_interval => unknown) does not exist
  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Please help me what can be reason of it?
I granted permission to my user following documenataion. It not helped
CREATE ROLE partman_user WITH LOGIN;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA partman TO partman_user;
GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA partman TO partman_user;
GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA partman TO partman_user;
GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL PROCEDURES IN SCHEMA partman TO partman_user;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA my_partition_schema TO partman_user;

I'm using postgresql-14

reason of error is missing of argument p_type := 'native' in partman.create_parent() function

Don't edit the question to add an answer, don't answer in a comment. If you found a solution, you're welcome to post a "self-answer" and accept it. Otherwise the thread's hanging as unanswered, regardless of SOLVED in the title and the solution in the comment.

thnaks you for comment i will do

Adding p_type := 'native' in partman.create_parent() function call solved the problem:
SELECT partman.create_parent(
    p_parent_table := 'public.test_table',
    p_control := 'last_seen',
    p_interval := '1 day',
    p_type := 'native'     --here
);

In pg_partman version 4.7.3 function partman.create_parent() has 4 mandatory arguments, p_type being one of them:
CREATE FUNCTION @extschema@.create_parent(
    p_parent_table text
    , p_control text
    , p_type text
    , p_interval text
    , p_constraint_cols text[] DEFAULT NULL 
    --...

In pg_partman version 5.0.1 only p_parent_table, p_control and p_interval aren't optional, so p_type can be omitted.

The p_type has a default value defined in the function, so it shouldn't be necessary to pass that. Did you also try to maybe SELECT partman.create_parent( p_parent_table := 'public.test_table'::text, p_control := 'last_seen'::text, p_interval := '1 day'::text );? the explicit type casts suggested by the error message might be enough. That, or even without the parameter names SELECT partman.create_parent( 'public.test_table'::text, 'last_seen'::text, '1 day'::text );

There's an example in the doc where they suggest to use only the 3 arguments, exactly like you tried initially, here. Are you sure it's only overriding p_type that solved the problem?

i thinked same too.
Current version of documentation - 5.0.1. But on production server was installed pg_partman version 4.7.3. In version 4.7.3 function partman.create_parent() don't have default value for argument p_type.

Good catch. I've added some details and links to the repo. Make sure you mark your answer as accepted to complete the thread.
